# ModalBottomSheet. перемещение только за определенную View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetbehavior, android-bottomsheet

Хочу добиться от ModalBottomSheet определенного поведения, а именно: перемещение MBS должно осуществляться только тогда, когда мы "дёргаем" за определенную view. например, dragHandle. в других же случаях, перетаскивание (drag) должно быть выключено. пытался добиться этого через onTouchListener, вешать его на нужную вьюшку и ставить флаг isDraggable в true, но это не помогло.

xml ModalBottomSheet:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainBottomSheetLayout"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ModalBottomSheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dragHandle"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/myRecView" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

behavior:

```
val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior
behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
behavior.skipCollapsed = true
```

Посоветуйте, куда копнуть.